# How to create function using list that corresponds content to content within the list?

Tags: python

The following string contains a list of positions and the corresponding persons. I have tried to create a function that, given a person, returns the list of positions the person has. But I get this error "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'split'". I am wondering if I could place a len function to make this code work (But I don't know where to place it, or do you have other solutions?

```
positions = '''\
== Positions ==
manager: Kari 
treasurer: Ole
IT manager: Liv
parking officer: Kari
event manager: Liv
garden consultant: Kari
fire officer: Kari
'''
positions=positions.split("\n")

def match_job_to_person(person):
    lines = match_job_to_person.split("\n")
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split(": ")
        if(words[0] == person):
            return words [1]
            print (words)


match_job_to_person("Kari")
match_job_to_person("Ole")
match_job_to_person("Liv")
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch:

```
lines = match_job_to_person.split("\n")
```

for

```
lines = positions.split("\n")
```

or

```
lines = positions
```

(since you did the newline split outside of your function already)

Your reference in the function to `match_job_to_person` is a reference to the function name, this isn't a string but a function, and as such, doesn't provide the `split` method.

There are other problems with your code, but this should move you past the initial error you're getting.